# Pattern for Ownership and References Between Multiple Controllers and Semi-Shared Objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns

For example, I have window  (non-document model) - it has a controller associated with it.  Within this window, I have a list and an *add* button.  Clicking the *add* button brings up another "detail" window / dialog (with an associated controller) that allows the user to enter the detail information, click ok, and then have the item propagated back to the original window's list.  Obviously, I would have an underlying model object that holds a collection of these entities (let's call the singular entity an Entity for reference).

Conceivably, I have just one main window, so I would likely have only one collection of entities.  I could stash it in the main window's controller – but then how do I pass it to the detail window?  I mean, I probably don't want to be passing this collection around - difficult to read / maintain / multithread.  I could pass a reference to the parent controller and use it to access the collection, but that seems to smell as well.  I could stash it in the appDelegate and then access it as a "global" variable via [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] - that seems a little excessive, considering an app delegate doesn't really have anything to do with the model.  Another global variable style could be an option - I could make the Entity class have a singleton factory for the collection and class methods to access the collection.  This seems like a bigger abuse than the appDelegate - especially considering the Entity object and the collection of said entities are two separate concerns.  I could create an EntityCollection class that has a singleton factory method and then object methods for interaction with the collection (or split into a true factory class and collection class for a little bit more OO goodness and easy replacement for test objects).  If I was using the NSDocument model, I guess I could stash it there, but that's not much different than stashing it in the application delegate (although the NSDocument itself does seemingly represent the model in some fashion).

I've spent quite a bit of time lately on the server side, so I haven't had to deal with the client-side much, and when I have, I just brute forced a solution.  In the end, there are a billion ways to skin this cat, and it just seems like none of them are terribly clean or pretty.  What is the generally accepted Cocoa programmer's way of doing this?  Or, better yet, what is the optimum way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your conceptual problem is that you're thinking of the interface as the core of the application and the data model as something you have to find a place to cram somewhere.

This is backwards. The data model is the core of the program and everything else is grafted onto the  data model. The model should encapsulate all the logical operations that can be performed on the data. An interface, GUI or otherwise, merely sends messages to the data model requesting certain actions.

Starting with this concept, it's easy to see that having the data model universally accessible is not sloppy design. Since the model contains all the logic for altering the data, you can have an arbitrarily large number of interfaces accessing it without the data  becoming muddled or code complicated because the model changes the data only according to its own internal rules.

The best way to accomplish universal access is to create a singleton producing class and then put the header for the class in the application prefix headers. That way, any object in the app can access the data model.

Edit01:

Let me clarify the important difference between a naked global variable and a globally accessible class encapsulated data model.

Historically, we viewed global variables as bad design because they were just raw variables. Any part of the code could alter them at will. This nakedness led to obvious problems has you had to continuously guard against some stray fragment of code altering the global and then bringing the app down.

However, in a class based global, the global variable is encapsulated and protected by the logic implemented by the encapsulating class. This encapsulation means that while any stray fragment of code may attempt to alter the global variable inside the class, it can only do so if the encapsulating class permits the alteration. The automatic validation reduces the complexity of the code because all the validation logic resides in one single class instead of being spread out all over the app in any random place that data might be manipulated.

Instead of creating a weak point as in the case of a naked global variable, you create strong and universal validation and management of the data. If you find a problem with the data management, you only have to fix it in one place. Once you have a properly configured data model, the rest of the app becomes ridiculously easy to write.

Comment: I think I agree with your overarching point.  A perspective change to focusing on the model seems appropriate.  Cocoa (and its tools) often seem to focus your attention on driving from the UI / view / controller rather than the model. The globally accessed model as seen in this light doesn't seem that bad, assuming it truly is a single shared collection (which I've generally posited that it is).

Comment: Yes, the user interface on the Mac and the iPhone has an almost hypnotic quality that inevitably draws the designers attention to the UI and making appear to be the most important part of the program. 

It's the age old problem of the pretty face versus personal character. Choosing a pretty face while ignoring character leads to heart break in the end. 

Coding is the same way. A pretty UI is only skin deep but a bad data model goes all the way to the bone.

Answer (score 2):

My initial reaction would be to use a "modal delegate," a lot like `NSAlert`s do. You'd create your detail window by passing a reference to a delegate, which the detail window would message when it is done creating the object. The delegate—which would probably be the controller for the main window—could then handle the "done editing" message and add the object to the collection. I'd tend to not want to pass the collection around directly.

Comment: I really like this solution – succinct and correlates with the pattern most often seen used by Apple in their own classes.

Answer (score 0):

I support the EntityCollection class. If you have a list of objects, that list should be managed outside a specific controller, in my opinion.

Comment: This isn't a bad suggestion, it sounds like you're suggesting the use of NSArrayController.

Answer (score 0):

I use the singleton method where the class itself manages it's own collections, setup and teardown. I find this separates the database/storage functionality from the controllers and keeps things clean. It's nice and easy to just call `[Object objects]` and have it return a reference to my list of objects.