# How to send All objects of Mutable Array to Another Class?

Tags: iphone

I want to send Mutable Array with all its objects from my First Class to Second Class. I have no idea how can i do this please anybody tell me the way...

Comment: See this [stackoverflow anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346951/iphone-how-i-can-access-data-in-a-view-controller-class-from-another-controller/2347108#2347108) All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourSecondClass.mutableArray_asAMemberVariable = [[yourFirstClass mutableArray_asAMemberVariable] copy];
```

This makes a copy out your firstClass mutable array and sends it to your second class.

Answer (score 0):

you make one declare mutable array and make it property on other class where you want to then just give like follow

vc.nsmutablearray = the_array_you_want_to_send;